# How to move a record from one collection to another collection using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Tried to move a record from one collection to another collection in mongodb using mongoose. But not working.I do not know to do it. I am new in mongoose.If anyone know please help me.

Getting error Like:

> DocumentNotFoundError: No document found for query "{ _id:
>   5ed6407d511657149c4ad65d }" on model "Xyz"

data.controller.js:

```
module.exports.movearecordToAnother = (req, res, next) => {
let from= req.query.delete;
let to= req.query.push;
let invoiceno = req.query.invoice;

mongoose.model(from).findOne({ invoice: invoiceno }, function(err, result) {

    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    } else {
        let swap = new(mongoose.model(to))(result);
        //swap._id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId();
        //swap.isNew = true
        result.remove();
        swap.save(); 
        console.log("Successful moved");
        res.json({ data: result, success: true, msg: 'Successful moved a record.' });

    } 
}); 
};
```

Comment: Hi there! I see you're commenting out `swap.isNew = true`, that is supposed to fix the error. Question: Were you having this error even when the `swap.isNew` line is uncommented? Also, can you try sending back the server response after the save is done, i.e either await the `swap.save` or put the `res.json(...)` in a call back to the `swap.save` and see if anything changes.

Comment: @Tunmee: Now it is working good..Thanks